# What is the good pratice to create a datavisualisation website?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, echarts

I am currently in the process of creating a website of timeseries data visualisation. The back-end is nodejs. I store all data in mySQL server. I use EJS Template.
The database is a subset of multiple campaigns of measurement.
Each campaign has about 1 500 000 datas displayed with echarts. My aim is to only visualize a range of data. For that i use datepicker.

I imagine that each selected range will redirect to a new query ([www.xxxx.com?query=xxx](http://www.xxxx.com?query=xxx)).
Is it a good pratice? Can i do that in front-end?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can get all data from your server with an HTTP Request. After that, you can display and modify the data that users can play with charts. You can check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare) example from `Highcharts`. It allows us to boost the charts with a large amount of data so that we can display it on the client-side effectively.

You can get data from the backend below format. Use Epoch like `1147651200000` and be careful UTC or local date and time.

```
 [
  [1147651200000,23.15],
  [1147737600000,23.01],
  [1147824000000,22.73],
  [1147910400000,22.83],
  [1147996800000,22.56],
  [1148256000000,22.88],
  [1148342400000,22.79],
  [1148428800000,23.50],
  [1148515200000,23.74],
  [1148601600000,23.72],
  [1148947200000,23.15],
  [1149033600000,22.65],
]
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.